# ASP.NET Core Web Application Template does not exist on Visual Studio 15

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, visual-studio-2017

I've installed Visual Studio 15.

When I want to add new project, the **ASP.NET Core Web Application (.NET Core)** does not exist in project templates.

I've installed **.NET Core** and I'm using it on VS 2015.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tooling for .NET core is not available in VS15 yet. https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/releasenotes/vs15-relnotes

> Visual Studio Tools for .NET Core availability
>
> Issue:
>
> Tooling support for .NET Core projects is not available in this
>   release of Visual Studio.
>
> Workaround:
>
> Support will be available in a future update of Visual Studio “15”.

Answer (score 0):

It is due to the .Net Core Tool which is yet not released for VS2015. So if you want to use it then you have to go for VS2017.